# HTTP Error 413 - Request Entity Too Large - on TranslateArray request

Tags: microsoft-translator

When I called Microsoft Translator Text API's [TranslateArray](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_TranslateArray), Error 413 (Request Entity is too Large)  occurred.

I recognize API limitations:

- The total of all texts to be translated must not exceed 10000 characters.
- The maximum number of array elements is 2000.

When the request's Content-Length header is greater than 30721, the request fails with a 413 error even though the above api limitations are observed.

is there any other limitation?

Comment: 30000 > 10000 no?

Comment: "10000 characters" limitation is the values of string tag in Texts tag. Content-Length include xml tag length.

Comment: you have 20k characters of xml tags, that are not inside text? I think you're pretty clearly hitting a 'request is too large' limit, and should consider splitting your request into smaller sections.

Comment: This case may not normally occur. if we attempt to test the upper limit of the limit (2000 array, 10000 characters) with the unit test code, using short sentences (eg "Hello", "Good Morning" ...), it will happen.

Comment: I understand that by dividing this into smaller sections the problem is solved.
However, I will use Translator API in Enterprise production environment, so 
 I would like to know clearly if there are restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still running into this issue, upgrading to the latest `google-cloud-translate` client should fix the issue. For more information, the PR [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/4977) fixed the problem for me, which was that the client was using GET requests instead of POST requests.

Note: This should also fix a related error of getting 411 (Length Required) when cutting off a piece of text to only translate the first N characters.